# How can I create a node and a relationship in the same statement when loading a CSV file?

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

How can I create a node and a relationship in Memgraph in the same statement when loading a CSV file?
For example:

```
company(short_name) ← :employed - employee (emp_id)
```

employee.csv looks like this:

```
emp_id, name
```

And the desired behavior would be like:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "o/people_nodes.csv" WITH HEADER AS row
CREATE (e:employee {emp_id: row.emp_id, name: row.name})
CREATE (c:Company {short_name: $short_name }) <- [:EMPLOYED] - (emp: Employee {emp_id : row.emp_id})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query I submitted should be able to create both nodes and relationships while importing from a CSV file.

I found a way to express it with one `CREATE` clause:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "o/people_nodes.csv" WITH HEADER AS row 
CREATE (c:Company {short_name: $short_name })<-[:EMPLOYED]-(e:employee {emp_id: row.emp_id, name: row.name})
```